# How to reduce the position of a div when linking menus with div based on div id with scroll in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some div and links,here I am linking my menu with some div based on id,When you click particular link,particular div will visible inside scroll.But here problem is that the div is hiding inside header bar.So I want to just bring it to down so that particuar div will be visible properly.Here is the updated code below https://plnkr.co/edit/pzZNvTVVle3BBaUAvs7x?p=preview

### HTML

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <style type="text/css">
    .scroll-div {

      margin-top: 10px;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .anchor {
      border: 2px dashed red;
      padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
    }

    .my-fixed-header > a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }
    .html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

  </style>
 <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

   <div class="my-fixed-header" style="position:fixed;border:1px solid;padding:20px;width:100%;background:yellow;">
   <a href="index.html#/#anchor{{x}}"  ng-click="gotoDiv(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]">
        Go to Div {{x}}
      </a>
   </div>
    <div class="scroll-div">      
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value ">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)">{{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### script.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

$scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {

          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
               console.log(x);


            a.isOpen = true;


          });



     };

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 6',
      id:'6',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I an understanding your question correctly, you could just add a padding to your scroll-div:

```
.scroll-div {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-top: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Or are you asking for a way to make it so the actual elements don't physically overlap?

Comment: yes actual element should scroll till just few pixel below so that it should not hide inside header bar,once you see the above plunker you can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I have moved your `.header` element inside of your `my-fixed-header` element and set `my-fixed-header` css to have:

```
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also changed the `.scroll-div` to have a top margin which pushes it down far enough to align with your fixed header.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rOjAVKPhNCAi5FW6

Comment: scroll will come in whole browser I have updated my plunker,not on the bases of div

Comment: i am having trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve here. if you want to have a fixed header - my answer shows how to get that working with your code. it doesn't matter if your container in which you are displaying your content is of a specific height (in which case the scroll bar will be only in this container), or if it isn't (in which case there will only be a scroll bar if your content exceeds the height of the page).

Comment: I updated plunker please check..my visible div is going inside menu pad,Can it possible to  scroll little below so that it should visible properly

Comment: I checked it before I wrote the comment above. It doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: I updated plunker please check..my visible div is going inside menu pad,Can it possible to scroll little below so that it should visible properly

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EexNgdBorp3b9vpldJwR?p=preview is this what you are looking for?

Comment: When you click menus that time also the particular  div should not go up,it should come down to visible properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187095/discussion-between-classicalconditioning-and-carreankush).